# Design a row in a table - CSS

Tags: html, css-tables

I'm trying to make a table that should look like that (this should be one row in the table):

[image]

But I'm new to CSS and its getting weird!
This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="instruct"><?= $value->CustomerName;?></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="instruct" style="width:60%;">
            <?= $value->Building;?>&nbsp;<?= $value->FloorRoom;?>
        </div>
        <div class="instruct" style="width:40%;">1986</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**and CSS:**

```
.instruct
{
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 8px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background: #FFEAFE;
    font-size: 105%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;
    transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Its not even close to looking like in the image above.

**edit for harry**

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `div`s within table? Wouldn't it be better to use `colspan` for the first row?

Comment: Harry, as i say i'm new to css.
If you can teach me how to do it right - i'll be glad!

Comment: Oh yeah, possible. It can be done like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Ukx76/)

Comment: Thanks Harry! and if i want to add an image to the first cell? like an arrow? (the text will be in the left corner and the arrow in the right corner?)
* the arrow sign tells people that the row can be pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colspan` attribute to achieve this layout without adding additional `div` tags within `td`. The numeric value assigned for the `colspan` instructs on how many columns should be merged into one.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>Tex1<img src='http://lorempixel.com/64/64' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tex2</td>
            <td>Tex3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>Tex1<img src='http://lorempixel.com/64/64' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tex2</td>
           <td>Tex3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
td { /* I have used a generic td selector for demo, but you can assign and use classes */
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 8px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background: #AA3333;
    font-size: 105%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;
    transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

tbody{
    display: block;
    background: #FFEAFE; /* the lighter background color for group */
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px; /* separator between each group */
}

img{ /* to float the image to the right */
    float: right;
}
td:hover{ /* for a simple hover transition effect */
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

[**Final Demo with Image and Hover Effect**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Ukx76/)

Comment: wow. great.
I need to add gap under the  "text2" and "text3"
so i can add a new row.
how do i do that?

Comment: text1, text2 and text 3 should be in a group (this is data about one person in the table).
Then, there should be another text1,text2 and text3 data for a second person.
That mean i need a gap between the two data so it will be easy to understand that its for two different people.

Comment: take a look on the main post. I edit it for you (added an image)

Comment: Not really. Adding padding is not the answer.. it still hard to recognized the first persion's info and the second

Comment: Yes. the second version (:

Comment: @user3282988: Wait, you can use [this option](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Ukx76/10/). It is even better and uses only one table with multiple tbody (allowed in HTML5).

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this..

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>Tex1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tex2</td>
        <td>Tex3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td
{
    background:rgb(241, 211, 211);
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 5px 5px;
}
```

**Fiddle:**   [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/57H6v/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like that :

The `colspan="2"` attribute in the first `<td>` will make this cell occupy the place of two cells.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="large" colspan="2">Text 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text 2</td>
        <td>Text 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Live example**

http://jsfiddle.net/58fNe/

Comment: Ok, you were 50 seconds faster :p

Answer (score 1):

You want to create this 3 div containers into a table cell ? 
Because if not, you should have a structure like this :

```
<table>
   <tr >
      <td colspan='2'>Text1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Text2</td>
      <td>Text3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Also, I can explain you how to position your divs in order to have your wanted result.

Comment: The <table> tag is the declaration of your table. Then, inside, you will put a <tr> tag for each line you want into your table. in your example, you need 2 lines, so let's put 2 <tr> tags.
Finally, each <td> tags represent a cell. You want only one cell in the first line, but twice the widths of the ones under. So you put in the first <tr> a <td> tag with colspan='2' attribute in order to precise to double the width. And in the second line, just put 2 normal <td> cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.instruct
   {
   float:left;
    padding: 8px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background: #FFEAFE;
    font-size: 105%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;
    transition: opacity 350ms ease-out;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think colspan with a separate table class will do your job =)

```
<td class="tdClass" colspan=100%>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E57t7/1/

Comment: -1 `colspan` _"contains a non-negative integer value that indicates for how many columns the cell extends_". `colspan=100%` is not valid HTML and `colspan` can only be expressed as _number of columns_. What you're saying there (assuming browser will ignore `%` error) is to have a cell with `colspan=100`. Also this is pretty weird and some browser will not render that correctly (`colspan` higher than column count). Same result would be `colspan=0` but AFAIK it's supported only by FF (and it's invalid in HTML 5). To use percentage you need `<colgroup>` stuff.